# How to call from within Python an application with double quotes around an argument using subprocess?

Tags: python-3.x, certutil

I'm trying to call **certutil** from inside **python**. However I need to use quotation marks and have been unable to do so. My code is as follows:

```
import subprocess
output= subprocess.Popen(("certutil.exe", "-view", '-restrict "NotAfter <= now+30:00, NotAfter >= now+00:00"' ), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
for line in output:
    print(line)

output.close()
```

I thought the single quotes would allow me to use double quotes inside the string.

Also I have tried using double quotes with the escape character (`\"`), however I keep getting the same error:

```
Unknown arg: -restrict \\NotAfter\r\n'
```

For some reason it seems to be translating `"` into `\\`.

Can anyone give insight as to why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
output=subprocess.Popen(("certutil.exe -view -restrict  \"NotAfter<=now+30:00,NotAfter>=now+00:00\"" ),stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
```

This is what was needed. I was passing the command as a command with 2 args. What I should have been doing was passing it as one big command with 2 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have Python in any version installed. But according to answer on [How do I used 2 quotes in os.system? PYTHON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16177142/3074564) and documentation of [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), **subprocess** handles requirement for double quotes on arguments with space automatically.

So you should need to use simply:

```
import subprocess
output= subprocess.Popen(("certutil.exe", "-view", "-restrict", "NotAfter <= now+30:00, NotAfter >= now+00:00" ), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
for line in output:
    print(line)

output.close()
```

And the command line used on calling **certutil** is:

```
certutil.exe -view -restrict "NotAfter <= now+30:00, NotAfter >= now+00:00"
```