# How do I not read '\t' as a tab in python strings

Tags: python, tshark

```
os.system("'C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe' -r B2.pcap -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time -e ip.src -e tcp.srcport -e ip.dst -e tcp.dstport -e ip.proto -e ip.flags.syn -e ip.flags.nf -e ip.flags.df -e frame.len -E header=y -E separator=, > traffic.csv")
```

I'm trying to run the above command in python but its reading the \t in the \tshark.exe part as a tab character. How do I solve this?

Comment: you can use raw string

Answer (score 2):

Raw strings start with the r symbol: r"string with \t \n"

Answer (score 1):

try

```
os.system("'C:\Program Files\Wireshark\\tshark.exe' -r B2.pcap -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time -e ip.src -e tcp.srcport -e ip.dst -e tcp.dstport -e ip.proto -e ip.flags.syn -e ip.flags.nf -e ip.flags.df -e frame.len -E header=y -E separator=, > traffic.csv")
```

Backslashes are used to "escape" characters and if you want to print out a backslash, you have to escape it with another backslash

Comment: My bad. Worked perfectly. Made a dumb mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Probably because this one is wrapped in string?

```
"'C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe'..."
```

try using raw string.

Comment: It would be more helpful to show how to use raw string - like this:  r”somestring”

Comment: Tried this. Same error.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
This is the error

Comment: I found a similar answer, try this maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177104/how-do-i-used-2-quotes-in-os-system-python/16177142#16177142