# Double quotes inside os.system echo

Tags: python, operating-system, system, python-3.8

Here is my code:

```py
import os
os.system("""echo pyklopp init my_model --config="'{\"model\":%s}'" --save "'test_%s/my_model.pth'" """ % ("MODEL", 0))
```

My output is:

```
pyklopp init my_model --config='{model:MODEL}' --save 'test_0/my_model.pth'
```

I want:

```
pyklopp init my_model --config='{"model":MODEL}' --save 'test_0/my_model.pth'
```

I want `model` inside double-quotes as shown above. Any suggestions?

I'm running on Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I used 2 quotes in os.system? PYTHON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177104/how-do-i-used-2-quotes-in-os-system-python)

Comment: I tried many things, including this, and when it prints double-quote, it ignores single-quotes.

Comment: Have you tried escaping both `'` and `"`?

Comment: Yep, I have tried that too!

Comment: That's weird, because that works for me

Comment: Escaping both will not print outer single-quotes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu you seem to have to double escape the `'` and `"`, like this:

```py
import os
os.system("""echo pyklopp init my_model --config=\\'{\\"model\\":%s}\\' --save \\'test_%s/my_model.pth\\' """ % ("MODEL", 0))
```

Which should give you:

```
pyklopp init my_model --config='{"model":MODEL}' --save 'test_0/my_model.pth'
```

---

### Old answer, for Windows

Try escaping both `'` and `"`, and remove the double quotes around `'{\"model\":%s}\'` and `'test_%s/my_model.pth\'`.

Like this:

```py
import os
os.system("""echo pyklopp init my_model --config=\'{\"model\":%s}\' --save \'test_%s/my_model.pth\' """ % ("MODEL", 0))
```

Which gives:

```
pyklopp init my_model --config="'{"model":MODEL}'" --save "'test_0/my_model.pth'"
```

**Edit:**

You don't even actually need to escape anything.

Without escaping:

```py
import os
os.system("""echo pyklopp init my_model --config='{"model":%s}' --save 'test_%s/my_model.pth' """ % ("MODEL", 0))
```

Will give you the same result.

Comment: Without escaping it will give `pyklopp init my_model --config={"model":MODEL} --save test_0/my_model.pth`. Missing single-quotes!

Comment: I don't, what Python version are you on?

Comment: Version 3.8 on Ubuntu

Comment: Hm, I'm on 3.7 Windows. Maybe that's it.

Comment: that might be the case then!

Comment: Can you try this on Ubuntu: `os.system("""echo pyklopp init my_model --config=\\'{\\"model\\":%s}\\' --save \\'test_%s/my_model.pth\\' """ % ("MODEL", 0))`? With double escapes

Comment: It worked. Thanks mate ;) Can you edit your answer with this so I can accept it?